# Wireless keyboard disconnects and then auto connects in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, broadcom, logitech, wireless-keyboards

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my dell laptop(Inspiron-5420). Wi-fi connection did not work out-of-the-box with this installation but after google search, I bumped into page

https://ibcomputing.com/install-wifi-driver-broadcom-bcm43142-linux/

and after following the steps there, it started working.

Now when using the logitech wireless keyboard/mouse(model MK220), the keyboard intermittently disconnects and then auto reconnects. The other peculiar behaviour I see is that whenever it disconnects, it automatically takes the screenshot and saves it.

Can anyone out there help in resolving this frequent disconnection issue of wireless keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With google search, came across the [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbCRf.jpg)

which mentioned the solution for HP laptop but when I applied the solution from there, it worked even on my Dell laptop.

---

HP laptop had an issue with keyboard key getting pressed by itself. It started taking a screenshot every now and then. Once the screenshot shortcut key was disabled in Ubuntu keyboard settings, it started playing with the scroll lock key.

To disable the laptop's built-in keyboard in Ubuntu, first you need to identify the device ID for the keyboard.

If you are connecting from a remote system via SSH, you need to run:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Now run `xinput –list` to get a list of all input devices.

```
hostonnet@pc4:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
hostonnet@pc4:~$
```

The `xinput` command should be run as the user that runs the GUI (Ubuntu logged in user).

The one above list what we need is:

```
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The ID is 10.

To disable the keyboard, run:

```
xinput set-int-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

To enable it, run:

```
xinput set-int-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 8 1
```

[image]

#### Method 2: Disabling on boot

Edit file /etc/default/grub.

```
vi /etc/default/grub
```

Find:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Replace it with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nokbd"
```

Regenerate grub.cfg with:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Reboot the laptop. The built-in keyboard will be disabled by default. There's no need to run the `xinput` command and manually disable it each time.